# Oracle 11g data pump 10 column limit

Tags: oracle11g, datapump

I am using an Oracle data pump to do a schema "rename."  There is a primary key column on all (2000) tables.  For example, I need to run this on all tables:

update mytable set mykey='foo2' where mykey='foo';

I would use the remap_data option of expdp to do this.  The problem is that there are some columns that I would need to do the rename on 10+ columns.  Has anyone had a problem like this and found a way to handle this?

Previously, I had tried using "Create Table As."  The problem would be having to recreate the schema structure for all of the tables (views/triggers/grants/indexes/constraints).  I am aware of the DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL package.  Offhand, doing a diff of the database schema before and after and recreating the diffs seems ugly.

I have also tried doing inserts on the table without any constraints or indexes, so I would only have to re-enable constraints and recreate the indexes, but I would like to try something faster.

I am using Oracle 11.2.0.3.0.

Comment: I did not quite get... _'update mytable set mykey='foo2' where mykey='foo';'_

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, your real problem (or goal) is  to 'RENAME' a schema. 
You chose to export / import (using a different NAME to achieve RENAME) using oracle data pump.
Then DROP old schema (if you feel redundant).

If this is correct, here are the steps, you can do to achieve your goal. I did it successfully on my DEV env. All objects (including PK, FKs) were imported successfully.

```
-- Export RMCORE_QA
expdp DIRECTORY=DMPDIR DUMPFILE=RMCORE_QA.dmp SCHEMAS='RMCORE_QA' LOG=RMCORE_QA_EXP_DP.lst  

-- Import using RMCORE_QA3
impdp DIRECTORY=DMPDIR DUMPFILE=RMCORE_QA.dmp REMAP_SCHEMA='RMCORE_QA:RMCORE_QA3' SCHEMAS='RMCORE_QA' LOG=RMCORE_QA_IMP_DP.lst TRANSFORM=OID:N
```

You can also compare objects b/w schemas by-

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME, STATUS, object_type FROM dba_objects WHERE owner LIKE 'RMCORE_QA'
MINUS
select OBJECT_NAME, STATUS, object_type from dba_objects where owner like 'RMCORE_QA3';
```

HTH. Let me know if i did not get your problem...